# Shape raycasting: Best way to determine last position which does NOT intersect something?

Tags: 2d, box2d, raycasting, intersect

I'm using Box2D (jBox2D specifically) and I'm trying to do a tetris-like block collision (i.e. stopping just before they overlap each other so they seamlessly interlock)

What is the simplest method to determine the last position along a 'ray' *before* the shape intersects another? (i.e. determine what position the block should end up in if it travels in a specific direction so that it interlocks smoothly with other blocks) Box2D seems to provide generic raycasting functions but I cannot see how to do this easily with the functions provided.

---

(Note: In general a block game can be modelled as a grid, and this greatly simplifies collision/destination detection, since you don't have to rely on actual 2D/3D properties. However it is not possible to use a grid like this in my situation)

Comment: Hmm, can't you just find the length the ray should travel to intersect the other object, subtract a tiny epsilon (`0.00001` or something), and use that distance?

Comment: @Blender: I was using a similar method until now (although I subtracted a very small amount continuously from the ray's end, checked for intersection, and then continued until intersection no longer occurred). The problem with this is just accuracy - sometimes the interlock will look perfect, sometimes it will look slightly off. I also just thought that there must be a better method

Comment: You mean you are testing with a ray x units long, and if it hits then you make x a bit smaller and try again, repeatedly until it doesn't hit? You don't need to do that because the raycast function (Box2D right?) will tell you how far away the intersection is. See here for a clearer description: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/raycasting

Then do what Blender said.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I have a way *around* this problem, at least for my case - once I work out the intersection point from the raycast as normal, I have concocted a few functions which can determine (based on the size and shape of the object intersected + intersecting) the position where the object should 'arrive' to mesh nicely with the other block. So I basically solve the same problem but not directly with the raycast itself. There are a few corner cases where it doesn't work that great, but it's sufficient for my project at the moment

I am still interested, however, whether there is an exact answer to the original question: Is there a method or variant atop of normal raycasting which **can** determine the last 'good' position of a shape before it intersects?

@iforce2d - Maybe I've misunderstood, but surely the information that Box2D give me will only ever be where the intersection is and how far it is from the start? Neither of which fully do what I want - I want the **last** point **before** intersection where the two shapes can be positioned so as not to intersect (i.e. as close together as they can possibly get without intersecting)

Comment: You should not comment @ people in your answers. If you want to discuss the problem further with people post those things as comments or even better, open a chat room. :)